# Couchbase dynamic views with different keys

Tags: nosql, couchbase, couchbase-view

I have an issue with Couchbase.

I don't know ahead of time the keys on which the query is made. What solutions is Couchbase offering me.

Keep in mind that I have big data set, order of hundred of millions.

**EDIT:** I want to do matchmaking on a collection stored, the criteria is not known ahead of time or is randomly set. That means I have to set a view on compile time. What are my options?

Comment: View is "precompiled" set of results. That's why it wotks fast. So word `dynamic` is not "compatible" with words `view` and `big data set`. So you need to rethink your data model or your question is just not correct enough. Can you provide some examples about your data model or about what you've tried to do with couchbase...

Comment: Can you give us more information about this? A view is an index that is build when document is saved (updated/created).

Comment: I want to do matchmaking on a collection stored, the criteria is not known ahead of time or is randomly set. That means I have to set a view on compile time. What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/). It's allow you to do dynamic queries.